# How do I download/extract font from a website?

Tags: fonts

I went to application > frames > fonts, then selected the one I want to save, but unlike other listed fonts there it displays weird characters and when I open it on a new page, instead of downloading it shows the same stuff.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Mkp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you're viewing is the actual .woff file, whereas usually it displays a nice preview - I'm not sure if this is due to the file format (I was able to preview .woff2 files), or some file corruption, but if you download that file, you should be able to reference it via the usual `@font-face`. You can right-click and hit "Save As" when viewing the file to save it - just make sure it's being saved with the correct extension (.woff in this case).